# yii - How to insert dynamic images for ajaxButton

Tags: php, yii

I am new guy for yii framework. I have inserted an ajax button for my project like this

```
<?php    
echo CHtml::ajaxButton($mm->name, CController::createUrl('/restaurant/type/id/' . $mm -> id), array('update' => '#data'));
?>
```

I want to insert the image for button background. That image should be from database and should be dynamic.

Please can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlOptions of the button

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton($mm->name, CController::createUrl('/restaurant/type/id/' . $mm -> id), array('update' => '#data'), array('style'=>'background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);'));
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt support alex..but i want to get dynamic images from database for buttons..